# Change taxonomy list automatically generated paths

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I made a dummy second hand car website, for which I made a taxonomy list "Popular brands". I've added this list to the front page, but each of the respective links (e.g. each brand) links to `popular-brands/[brand]` instead of `brand/[brand]`, how I'd like it to be.

The first is generated automatically upon creating this block view. Can I alter this path to become the latter?

The case can be seen live at [ikhoefgeen.be](http://ikhoefgeen.be) (site is in Dutch by default, I'm not sure wether or not it automatically displays in English).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)?

Check patterns at admin/config/search/path/patterns and then update URL aliases

Comment: Yes, I am using pathauto. The problem is that the aliases that I would like to create already exist (the faulty paths should point/redirect to the ones already existing). How should I solve that?

Comment: You can try with some 301 redirects in the .htaccess 

Example: `RedirectMatch 301 popular-brand/brand brand/brand/ ` or `RedirectMatch 301 popular-brand/(.*)$ brand/$1`or I think [globlar redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module should do the trick –

Comment: I ended up using the Redirect module, thanks for your answer anyway!